# MySQL query to display records on not viewed or in last 10 days

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 3 tables (customers, messages and message_threads). I want to do a query that returns messages that haven't been read from the message_threads table as the first check, and/or IF they have been read, then only display messages from the last 10 days.

The OR with INTERVAL 10 DAY is not bringing the correct records in the `ORDER BY`. If I remove the OR condition then it works. This is my current query:

```
SELECT 
    c.customer_name, 
    c.customer_profile_image, 
    m.message_id, 
    m.contract_id, 
    m.message_subject, 
    m.last_updated, 
    mt.date_created, 
    mt.date_viewed
FROM t_customers_tenants c 
JOIN t_customers_messages m 
    ON (c.customer_id = m.tenant_id) 
JOIN t_customers_message_threads mt 
    ON (m.message_id = mt.message_id)                                               
WHERE m.customer_id = 7866                                                 
    AND mt.created_by = 'tenant'
    AND (mt.date_created > mt.date_viewed OR mt.date_created >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 10 DAY)
GROUP BY m.message_id
ORDER BY mt.message_thread_id DESC
```

When the OR statement is included, then it seems like the ORDER BY doesn't work.

Many thanks for all your help. I have included the SQLFiddle below, and as you can see the last record has 0000-00-00 00:00:00 as the date_viewed but it won't display this in the result returned from executing the query.

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e5e05

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sure, I will just arrange for you.

Comment: You keep referring to `order by` in ways that don't make sense. Is all the data coming back? Is date viewed greater than date created the right way to test for unread?

Comment: I have included the SQL Fiddel in the main description - much appreciated!

Comment: @GordonLinoff please check the description

Comment: @shawnt00 please check the description

Comment: That unviewed items meets both criteria. I still don't understand the question

Comment: The first condition should be if date_viewed = 0 else if its not 0 then check if the last message created was within 10 days else there is nothing outstanding. Do you get it @shawnt00?

Comment: If you look at the SQLFiddle data, the last record in the database table for date_viewed = 0 but the query is not returning 0 in the result set despite the ORDER BY being set as message_thread_id DESC, but if you remove OR mt.date_created >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 10 DAY from the query then that is the correct result. It seems like the query is checking INTERVAL 10 DAY rather than date_viewed check due to the OR statement

Comment: That's actually not a valid date

Comment: @shawnt00 I understand it's not I was meant to say 0000-00-00 00:00:00. I have updated the main description to include how the result set looks like, but as the last record in the table is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 then it should be displayed not the date of the record before it.

Comment: I have been playing around with it and a sub query with an IFNULL() works and returns the right results.

Comment: You shouldn't need a subquery for a simple check like this.

Comment: @shawnt00 if you check the SQLFiddle I have left the query in there for you to check, but it just feels "dirty" rather than simple. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e5e05/31 I will deal with the date check in the code based on the last_updated. Let me know your thoughts?

Comment: Your subquery says: does this message have any unread threads. The `order by` is unnecessary and going back to earlier comments I wonder why that keeps coming up. The `ifnull()` (I think) is just casting to a string to work around a SQL Fiddle error on the zero date. I don't see this doing what you had originally asked. My understand of the relationship between messages and threads is unclear. There are definitely other ways to do this though.